# Proof of Abstract Weierstrass M-test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

**Abstract M-test:** Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed vector space. Then $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ is a Banach space if and only if

- for every sequence $(x_k)_k\subset V$, if $\sum_k \|x_k\|$ converges then $\sum_k x_k$ converges in $(V,\|\cdot\|)$.

The "$(\Rightarrow)$" direction is clear. But there's the other direction in the proof:

> **$(\Leftarrow):$** Suppose $(x_n)_n\subset V$ is Cauchy. Let $n_1\in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy $m,n\ge n_1\implies \|x_m-x_n\|<1$. Inductively choose $x_{k+1}\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_{k+1}\ge n_k$ and $m,n\ge n_{k+1}\implies \|x_m-x_n\| <\frac{1}{2^k}$. Then each $\|y_j\|:=\|x_{n_{j+1}}-x_{n_j}\|<\frac{1}{2^j}$, for $n_{j+1} > n_j \ge n_1$. So that $\sum_j \|y_j\| < \|y_0\| + \sum_j \frac{1}{2^j}$, which converges.
>
> Now, $x_{n_k}=x_{n_1}+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1} (x_{n_{j+1}}-x_{n_j})=y_0+\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k-1} y_j \longrightarrow^{n\to\infty} y_0+\sum_j y_j$. Thus $(x_{n_k})_k$ converges, hence $(x_n)_n$ converges as well.

I don't completely get the idea behind this proof.

- Why is this particular construction of a series used? Couldn't we have just said that, since $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence whose associated series converges absolutely, and since its absolute convergence implies convergence, $(x_n)_n$ converges, and thus $V$ is complete?

Comment: I think you're confusing series and sequences. A Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n$ is a sequence. You don't know anything about the convergence of the series $\left( \sum_{k=1}^n x_n \right)_n$, in general it won't converge.
For example $\left( 1- \frac{1}{n!} \right)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ but the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( 1- \frac{1}{n!}\right) clearly doesn't converge.

Comment: It would probably help a little if you were to change the letter of the sequence in the M-test from $x$ to $a$, so that the terms of the series have no intuitive resonance with the members of the Cauchy sequence.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: @zhw. For some reason this is called the Abstract Weierstrass M-test. But I know that there is a different Weierstrass M-test that is used to test sequences for convergence.

Comment: @Demophilus That was a typo, I've just edited my post. We know that if the associated series of a sequence converges then the sequence must converge as well.

Comment: @sequence But that's precisely my point, you don't know that the associated series converges. You need to prove that every Cauchy sequence converges in the space. What you're saying is that every Cauchy sequence whose associated series converges, converges. This last statement is trivially true in any normed space.

Comment: I suppose the "associated series" is $\sum (x_n - x_{n-1})$? There's no reason to assume that that converges absolutely. We must extract a subsequence of $(x_n)$ to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given a normed linear space $(V,\|\,\|)$ with the following additional propery: for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $V$ such that $\sum \|x_n\| < \infty,$ the series $\sum x_n  $ converges to an element of $V.$ We want to conclude $(V,\|\,\|)$ is complete.

You write "Couldn't we have just said that, since $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence whose associated series converges absolutely, and since its absolute convergence implies convergence, $(x_n)_n$ converges, and thus $V$ is complete?"

Answer: No. We need to start this way: Let $(x_n)$ be a Cauchy in $(V,\|\,\|).$ Put yourself on pause here. What "associated series converges absolutely"? I'll stop here for now. Can you answer this question?

Comment: Let $(x_n)_n\subset V$ be a sequence such that $\sum_n \| x_n \| <\infty$ implies $\sum_n  x_n  <\infty$. Then this implies that $(x_n)_n$ converges (so it is Cauchy) in $V$.

The only thing here, however, is that there may be Cauchy sequences whose associated series does not converge. So we don't know if all Cauchy sequences in $V$ converge in $V$.

Comment: @sequence The first sentence in your comment makes no sense, and you haven't answered my question.

Comment: Why does not it make sense? I think I just repeated the condition that we were given in this problem. For answering your question, I probably misunderstood it. The associated series that converges absolutely is $\sum_n \|x_n\|$. @zhw.

Comment: In the proof, as far as I can see, we take a Cauchy sequence and show that its associated series must necessarily be absolutely convergent. But from this, why do we need to show that the associated series is convergent, if we are given that absolute convergence implies convergence? Moreover, $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|)$ is Banach, and $(\frac1n)_n$ is Cauchy, but its associated series is not absolutely convergent...

Comment: Oops, for that first sentence, I should've said "implies $\sum_n x_n$" converges.